# how to do clustering of markers on google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

well i am trying to do clustering of markers on google map. i have found this example http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/simple_example.html
but i am not able to understand the use of following code in it-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/markerclusterer';
  if (document.location.search.indexOf('packed') !== -1) {
    script += '_packed';
  }
  if (document.location.search.indexOf('compiled') !== -1) {
    script += '_compiled';
  }
  script += '.js"><' + '/script>';
  document.write(script);
</script>
```

what is the full src that is used there. when i copy the code and use it on my laptop it is not working. please explain why? and what are the best ways to do clustering of markers on google map.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/markerclusterer';
  if (document.location.search.indexOf('packed') !== -1) {
    script += '_packed';
```

if the URL of your page contains the string 'packed', it includes the script at "../src/markercluseter_packed.js"

```
  }
  if (document.location.search.indexOf('compiled') !== -1) {
    script += '_compiled';
```

if the URL of your page contains the string 'compiled', it includes the script at "../src/markercluseter_compiled.js"

```
  }
  script += '.js"><' + '/script>';
  document.write(script);
```

oherwise it includes the script at "../src/markerclusterer.js"

```
</script>
```

Do any of those files exist in the ../src/ directory relative to your page on your laptop?